# Pagination with filters using Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to setup pagination for one of my views, but the results are filtered, I am wondering how I could do something like this.

```
products_product_name = Product.query.filter(Product.product_name.contains(search_name)).paginate(1, 20)
```

Comment: The paginate method can be called on any query object from Flask-SQLAlchemy. flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination(query, page, per_page, total, items) can be used to.
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/

Comment: But how can I use it in a query where I use a filter like this?

Comment: Oh, I guess I  can just bacically do it like that, but just a question that isn't directly related to this one, is there a way I can display the current and the orevious pages of pagination at once? Btw thx

Comment: You should take a look at https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination. He created a query, then passes it to another that uses order_by, and applies pagination on th one. But maybe you can directly apply pagination after the filter method. For you second question: you could do 2 queries or do a bigger one by changing the per_page option, to get double number of value.

Comment: Yeah but my idea was to like at start show 20 and then when show more is clicked instead of switching the page it would show 40, then 60 etc. But I guess I could take the page variable and whenever querying display 20*page_num

Comment: This is made with JavaScript and API calls. When user clicks on the button, it creates a request to get 20 mores items and then update the page.

Comment: Ohhh ty, but could you help me understand what each line does?

Comment: "each line" can you detail ?

Comment: Oh I thought you were talking about the other persons answer, thought it was the same person, oops, oh I see, will try looking into that, ty.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it:

`model.query.filter_by(id=1).paginate(page=1, per_page=2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add some filtering logic similar to these:

```
if args["seen"]:
    query = query.filter(Product.seen == args["seen"])
if args["starred"]:
    query = query.filter(Product.starred == args["starred"])

# Descending sort by the field specified
if args["sort"].startswith("-"):
    field = args["sort"].replace("-", "")
    sort_by = getattr(Product, field).desc()
else:
    sort_by = getattr(Product, args["sort"]).asc()
query = query.order_by(sort_by).paginate(
    page=args["page"], per_page=args["per_page"]
```

Comment: Well, as it turns out that the way I bacically did it works(when making the items object I had placed () after "items"), but is there a benefit of doing it like your example?

Comment: Also I am not quite sure how your exmplae works, but if you have the time to explain, I would be happy to know.